# why is my sprite.Group list empty when I add objects to it?

Tags: python, pygame

I want to make it so that when there are more then 3 objects stored in  `bullet_group` it wouldnt add objects to it but for some reason my list stays empty even though I have objects stored in it. Why is that happening?

```py
bullet_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
bullet_group2= pygame.sprite.Group.sprites(bullet_group)
enemy_group = pygame.sprite.Group()

prev_time = time.time()
game_active = False

gameName = pygame.font.Font('font/Pixeltype.ttf',80).render('Asteroids',False,(51,153,255))
gameName_rect = gameName.get_rect(center = (400,70))
text2 = test_font.render('Press "space" to run',False,(51,153,255))
text2_rect = text2.get_rect(center = (400,340))
while True:
    dt = time.time() - prev_time
    prev_time = time.time()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if game_active:
            display_score()
            if len(bullet_group2) <= 3 :
                print(bullet_group2)
                if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                    bullet_group.add(player.create_bullet())
```

Comment: typo: `bullet_group` vs `bullet_group2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are checking the length of `bullet_group2` but then adding the bullets to `bullet_group`. As a result, the length of `bullet_group2` never increases, and you will always be able to keep adding bullets.

Try something like this:

```
if len(bullet_group) <= 3 :
    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        bullet_group.add(player.create_bullet())
```